# не работает size в jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
var n = $('div').size(); // не работает сайз. 
alert(n); // алерт вообще не выполняется.
```

Используя тот же get, вместо сайз:

```
var n = $('div').get(0); // всё работает возвращает первый элемент. 
alert(n); // работает
```

Comment: Ошибки есть? Какие? И причем тут `.get(0)`  который возвращает дом объект?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).size is not a function jq.js:3793

Comment: странно, у меня работает. как альтернатива n.length :)
может у вас jquery >= 1.8. size устарел

Comment: привел get(0) для того, чтобы сомнений не было насчет того, что есть ли у меня вообще div элементы

Comment: @Ваня `size` устарел с версии `1.8` ...вместо него используйте `.length `...... смотрите версию своей жиквери.......

Comment: Спасибо, смотрю уроки 5 летней давности :(